# Cannot Download Criteo 1TB Click Data

Tags: azure-blob-storage, criteo

Based on https://ailab.criteo.com/download-criteo-1tb-click-logs-dataset/,

"Download:
The dataset is hosted on Azure ML.
Each day can be downloaded at http://azuremlsampleexperiments.blob.core.windows.net/criteo/day_XX.gz, where XX goes from 0 to 23.

The following command downloads all days:
curl -O [http://azuremlsampleexperiments.blob.core.windows.net/criteo/day_{`seq](http://azuremlsampleexperiments.blob.core.windows.net/criteo/day_%7B%60seq) -s ‘,’ 0 23`}.gz
"

But it seems azuremlsampleexperiments.blob.core.windows.net no longer works? How do I download the data?

Comment: I ran in to the same issue.